# Export Excel to CSV with pipe delimiter without changing List Separator settings

Tags: excel, csv

I need to export an Excel file as CSV to import into a database.  I cannot use commas because there are commas in some text fields.  Things I have tried that did not work well:

- Changing commas in text to periods. This works, but not great.
- Change Control Panel settings and changing "List separator" settings to a pipe.  This also works, but then I have to use pipe in formulas in Excel, which is not great.

Are there any other options?

Comment: Is using VBA Macro to do this acceptable? If acceptable then I can post a VBA Macro.

Comment: There's literally no reason to make a macro for this.  There are reliable utilities which accomplish this in industry standard ways.

Answer (score 1):

Using commas works fine.  Commas that exist in text are not considered as separators when exporting from Excel into CSV because they are wrapped in quotes.  All database import utilities should account for this by now.

If you don't have commas in your text:
`1,2,3,4,this is text`

If you do have commas in your text:
`1,2,3,4,"this, is text"`

CSV imports won't consider commas as delimiters that are wrapped in text.

Comment: This is a terrible answer, the amount of times I've had a column break everything because one cell contains something like "Hello world, ", when you split on a comma, then you have to track down by number of fields. Don't ever do this.

Comment: So, your solution is to never put commas in fields?  CSV means Comma Separated Values.  If you choose another delimiter it is no longer a CSV.

Comment: Neither point is true. In windows the separator is set in your region settings, and windows will use that in csv files. I didn't say never put commas in fields, I said never use a comma as a separator. In order of increasing amount of grief I've had with separators, 'I', '\t', ',' . Using speech marks to mark out text, means you need a state machine to parse it rather than a Split command. Also, pray you never get any csv from the EU, some countries there use a comma as a decimal point.

Comment: I'm not advocating for commas.  I prefer pipes.  The point being that OP asked a question about CSVs without understanding how they are commonly parsed.  In any case, the points I made are completely true.  If you are conflating CSV with the .csv format, that's on you.  .csv is no different than .txt in the sense that they are just flat files.

Answer (score 1):

You can use TEXTJOIN formula of Excel to concatenate all columns you want with a specific delimiter like the pipe.

Example for the columns below:

[image]

you can use the formula like below, one for each row above:

=TEXTJOIN("|",FALSE,A1,B1,C1,D1)

=TEXTJOIN("|",FALSE,A2,B2,C2,D2)

The result will be:

[image]

Finally, you can save this result as a text file.

Answer (score 1):

Open the xls or xlsx file in Excel, save in .ods format (this step avoids some problems).
Close Excel and open the ods file with Libreoffice and save as csv. It will allow you to specify the delimiting character *and* offer to enclose all fields in quotes.

[image: Libreoffice screen snip]

Answer (score 0):

You should enclose all fields with quotes:
"value 1","value,2","value3"

Comment: except numerics